# C# - Page Redirection not working properly

Tags: c#, asp.net, redirect, tabs, window

I have the following code in C#:

```
if (function.Equals("Larger50"))
{
      Request req = new Request();
      string result = req.doRequest("function=" + function + "&num=" + number, "http://localhost:4000/Handler.ashx");

      if (result.Equals("True") || result.Equals("true"))
      {
            Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Page.GetType(), null, "window.open('http://localhost:4000/Larger.aspx?num=" + number + "', '_newtab')", true);
       }

       if(result.Equals("False") || result.Equals("false"))
       {
             Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Page.GetType(), null, "window.open('http://localhost:4000/Smaller.aspx', '_newtab')", true);
       }

       if(result.Equals("Error") || result.Equals("error"))
       {
             Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Page.GetType(), null, "window.open('http://localhost:4000/ErrorPage.htm', '_newtab')", true);
       }

       Session["result"] = result;
       Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Page.GetType(), null, "window.location.href = 'Results.aspx'", true);
}
```

The result variable can have any one of three values (if the server responds):

i) true
ii) false
iii) error

The main problem with this code is that the new tab script in each of the three if statements work as they should.  However, the last script which opens the Results.aspx page is not executing for some reason or another.  The script is written well as it executed perfectly if all the other code is commented out.  How should I solve the problem?

I tried replacing it with Response.Redirect("Results.aspx") however then this exeuctes and all the other three scripts never execute.

Comment: add in the full url to Results.aspx

Comment: Results.aspx is a page in the current project I am working.  All the other URLs are to a server machine.

Comment: The scripts work perfectly on their own, however when they are combined together they don't work for some reason or another.  It's like the first script to be encountered executes, and the next scripts are ignored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should register these all at once, rather than in two separate statements:

```
if (function.Equals("Larger50"))
{
      Request req = new Request();
      string result = req.doRequest("function=" + function + "&num=" + number, "http://localhost:4000/Handler.ashx");

      string scriptVal = "";

      if (result.Equals("True") || result.Equals("true"))
      {
            scriptVal = "window.open('http://localhost:4000/Larger.aspx?num=" + number + "', '_newtab');";
       }

       if(result.Equals("False") || result.Equals("false"))
       {
            scriptVal = "window.open('http://localhost:4000/Smaller.aspx', '_newtab');";
       }

       if(result.Equals("Error") || result.Equals("error"))
       {
            scriptVal = "window.open('http://localhost:4000/ErrorPage.htm', '_newtab');";
       }

       Session["result"] = result;

       scriptVal += "window.location.href = 'Results.aspx';";

       Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Page.GetType(), null, scriptVal, true);
}
```

See the docs on [`ClientScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z9h4dk8y.aspx), specifically:

> A startup script is uniquely identified by its key and its type.
>   Scripts with the same key and type are considered duplicates. Only one
>   script with a given type and key pair can be registered with the page.
>   Attempting to register a script that is already registered does not
>   create a duplicate of the script.

In your case, the type and key are the same in both of the scripts you register.

You could uniquely identify them with a key, and then register them separately.  But you have to keep in mind that the order of execution is not guaranteed:

> The script blocks are not guaranteed to be output in the order they
>   are registered.